# ESTA - Changes in job role and emergency contact

Tags: usa, esta

I applied for an ESTA one year ago to visit the US for the first time and got approved. At that time I was a student and didn't have any current employer, therefore I put the information about my previous one. Now that I am no longer a student, I got a full-time job. Since I am going to visit NY again during Christmas, should I reapply for a new ESTA and put the information about my current employer?

Also, when I applied the first time, I used my best friend phone number as emergency contact, but now that number is no longer active. Should I reapply for a new ESTA to update this info too?

Thank you to everyone who's going to help!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to apply for a new ESTA. This is only necessary if you have a new passport, your name, nationality or gender marker has changed, or the answer to any of the the yes/no questions has changed.

You are not expected to apply for a new ESTA if you make a new trip with a different purpose, or your occupation has changed.

You may, if you wish, update the answer to the "address in the USA" question, however, this is not necessary and I would wager most regular travellers to the US do not do this, but if you wish to remove your friend's contact number then you can.

This information can be found in the FAQ: https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/faq

Comment: One of the questions on the ESTA form is "Do you have a current or previous employer?" , with the options of 'yes' and 'no'. My presumption is that the "yes/no" questions referred to in the FAQ answer only relate to the "eligibility" questions, however by a literal interpretation, if the OP answer 'no' to this question before, then their answer has changed...

Comment: Thank you! 
If I wanted to make an application for a new ESTA, should I need to wait till it expires or could I do it while it is still valid?

Comment: @Doc Yeah that was my interpretation as well, because if you answer yes it leads you to answer what your job is.

Comment: @Fede You can reapply while it is still valid (of course, because if your answer to the stated questions changes, then you must) but IMO it is completely unnecessary for you.